# Why I can not create Axis2 Web Server

Tags: java, web, service, webserver, apache-axis

I created a dynamic web project to create an Axis2 Web Server Service.

Target runtime env is Apache Tomcat 9.

Modify to configuration, i selected Axis2 Web Services.

Then I download the Axis2 Binary distribution from the Apache web page. Then i go to the window -> preferences -> Web Services -> Axis2 Preferences. Later, I browse the Axis2 runtime location to my downloaded Axis2 Binary distribution.

Later, I created a class like below on my project

```
public class HelloWS {
    public String hello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

    public int toplam(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Then I create a web service, then select axis2 and tomcat. Then next -> next -> finish.

But whenever I run the application, it gets this result:

**javax.servlet.ServletException: File [/WEB-INF/include/httpbase.jsp] not found**

Some web page says that attach the Axis2 WAR distribution to solve it, but  I don't know how I can do this?

Comment: You can download the WAR distribution here: http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.html It contains a WAR file to deploy in Tomcat. Once deployed, httpbase.jsp will be accessible.

Comment: You can also drop the axis2 war distributions contents into your WebContent directory, if you wish.